# Python: '%2s'% doesn't work after breaking the row

Tags: python, numbers, row, spaces

i need to produce output with specified number of spaces. It is a table with some columns, for saving output in to the file i use line:

```
save_line = ('%8s' % label[each_atom + str(int(k) + 1)] +
             '%10s' % str(int(i) + 1) +
             '\n' + 
             '%2s' % x[i] +
             '%20s' % y[i] +
             '%20s' %z[i] +
             '\n')
```

but the `'%2s'%x[i]` doesn't produce two spaces in output. I cant use `+"  "+` there. Any ideas what I can do?

Here is output of my code:

```
      C1         1
2.482705            1.332897           13.175184
```

And finally here's how my output should looks (it is example from another input, my task is to produce my basing on this):

```
      C1         1
  2.42416980          4.14117720          4.71196000
```

It is no problem to change any number of spaces  between any columns. The only one that doesn't work is the first one in every second row. It doesn't mater that the numbers don't mach. The problem is in the spaces.

Comment: Why don't you use `str.format`?

Comment: works for me. Have you example output?

Comment: Cleaned your code.  It's not clear what you're asking.  Does the question have anything to do with the data you added here? Or does it have to do with `'%2s' % x[i]` not doing what you expect?  What's `x[i]` in this case?

Comment: Ok, it works now. Sorry for problem. That was my first try with Python.

Answer (score 0):

Please combine those templates

```
save_line = "%8s%10s\n%2s%20s%20s\n" % (
    label[each_atom + str(int(k) + 1)],
    str(int(i) + 1),
    x[i],
    y[i],
    z[i])
```

The right side of the % operator should be a tuple. None of your values are tuples (from what I can see) and that's a great way to get output you do not expect. If you only want to format one item:

```
print "Hello %s!" % ("world",)
```

Note the trailing comma. This is because

```
("World")
```

is a string (with parenthesis around it), while

```
("World",)
```

is a tuple containing one item.

Answer (score 0):

> but the '%2s'%x[i] doesn't produce two spaces in output. I cant use +"  "+ there. Any ideas what I can do?

Why?
The number after % is the size of a new string field.

```
print '%3s' % 'why'
>>why
print '%4s' % 'why'
>> why
```

The size is 4 symbols for 'why' string = ' why'.
You have only 1 left space for 3 letters word if you use '%4s'.

Also, you can use '-'.
If your string is 's' and you use '%-2s', you will get new string 's ', with 1 space after your string. You can use it also in your string formatting tasks.

```
>>> print "%-5s%s" % ("N", "Q")
N    Q
>>> print "%5s%s" % ("N", "Q")
    NQ
>>> print "%5s%5s" % ("N", "Q")
    N    Q
>>> '%.1s' % 'Hello!'
'H'
>>> '%.2s' % 'Hello!'
'He'
```

And you can use value for tuple:

```
>>> '%.*s' % (2, 'Hello!')
'He'
```

Thank you,